# Debounce library hook of a lib that make API call on React

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, lib, react-query

I'm using a library that connect to a client with a provider and offer an hook that make an API call and returns some data (similar to react-query).

Sometimes happen that some parents components, of the component where I use that hook, refresh their state so the hook called and then it make a lot of API calls.

I can't modify the library hook and I can't create nested hooks (react standard rules) so how can I debounce an hook that make an API call? Is there a way to do this?

**Example:**

Using Chakra UI hook `useBreakpointValue` and resizing the window (for example dragging console) the component refresh and the `useAPI` is recalled a lot of time.

```js
function ParentComponent() {
    const mode = useBreakpointValue({base: false, lg: true});
    return <Component mode={mode} />;
}

function Component({mode}) {
  const {data, isLoading} = useAPI(); // Need to be debounced

  if(isLoading) return <Loader />;
  return (<div>{data.result.map((row) => <Row item={row} mode={mode} />)}</div>)  
}
```

Comment: Show some code or it never happened.

Comment: @morganney added

Comment: You can mirror the `mode` in `ParentComponent` to local state, like `stateMode` and then pass that as a prop to `Component` instead. You can debounce the mirrored state value inside a `useEffect` that only runs when `mode` changes. Like what is done here: https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

Comment: so do I understand it right that custom hook `useAPI` does not have any parameters? so calls happens not by condition but each time re-render happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SWR library or React.memo

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const mode = useBreakpointValue({base: false, lg: true});
    return <Component mode={mode} />;
}

const Component = React.memo(function({mode}) {
  const {data, isLoading} = useAPI(); // Need to be debounced

  if(isLoading) return <Loader />;
  return (<div>{data.result.map((row) => <Row item={row} mode={mode} />)}</div>)  
})
```

Or in SWR https://swr.vercel.app/

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "uniq key of this request",
    ()=>useAPI().data
  );


  if(!data) return <Loader />;
  return (<div>{data.result.map((row) => <Row item={row} mode={mode} />)}</div>)
```